# Creating a foreign key contstraint on non primary or unique key

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

How to use foreign key constraint on non primary key?

For example I have two tables `account` and `transactions`. I want to check the `acname` in table `transactions` is one of the `acname` in table `account`.

```
table account (acno, acname, bal, type)
table transactions (tid, acno, acname, bal, credit/debit, datetime)
```

Here `transactions.acname` should be equal to `account.acname`.

Please see this er diagram for help:

[image]

Comment: Please show the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe plz see the image for clarification

Comment: Text is better than images. Anyway, do `tac_no` in `transactions` and `ac_no` in `account_master` reference another table? Do they have to be the same?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Why is there an account name in the transactions table? Is this because an account name can change, but you want to know the account name at transaction time? Then you can't have a constraint anyway, because it would be allowed for the transaction's account name not to be in the account table. If there is no reason for the account name to be in the transactions table, then remove it.

Comment: [mre] please. [ask] [help]

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes they do have to be same as those are the transactions made by accounts and also i dont want to have a join coz th data can result in many entrie

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yes i need to display name too ... and i cant use it like foriegn key constraint coz it can be same for two different accounts

Comment: Then Gordon Linoff's anser is the correct one. You need to normalize your data.

Answer (score 1):

Fix your data model!

That is, don't store both the `acno` and `acname` in both tables.  Instead, store `acno` in `accounts`.

Then when you want the name, use `join`:

```
select t.*, a.acname
from transactions t join
     accounts a
     on t.acno = a.acno
```

The basic rule is that you want foreign key constraints to be linked to the *primary keys* of reference tables (although most databases allow them to unique keys).  And, you do not want to repeat data across tables.

Although MySQL lets you define foreign key references to non-primary keys, there is not a reason to do so.

Comment: Postgres  (and Oracle) will also let you define foreign keys to non-primary keys as long as the target is a unique constraint.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . MySQL allows a foreign key reference to any *indexed* column(s), not just unique columns.  I still recommend only defining the references to primary keys, unless you have a really, really good reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff "there is not a reason to do" There is a reason to do so: to enforce a constraint when appropriate. A well-designed table doesn't necessarily have only one CK or UNIQUE. Although MySQL FKs should be to PK or UNIQUE NOT NULL.

Comment: @philipxy . . . I don't see what a constraint has to do with a foreign key constraint to a non-primary key.  The two are orthogonal.  You can still have unique constraints with foreign keys to primary keys only.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't understand your comment. A table can have multiple UNIQUE column sets, neither a subset of the other, each with a column set elsewhere whose non-NULL subrow values must appear in it (ie a certain relational constraint holds), hence both CK constraints should be declared, one of which can be via PK & the other(s) UNIQUE, and both FK constraints should be declared. So it is not the case that "there is not a reason to" "define foreign key references to non-primary keys". (UNIQUE NOT NULL in MySQL.)

Comment: @GordonLinoff i dont want to use join coz it has to store  many entries which will be bad for my application also name shouldn't be unique

Comment: @KapilJaiswal . . . Something is wrong with your data model.  You would seem to need another table where `acname` *is* unique.